# Update two elements of array on single operation on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this one:

```
 {  
 name:'name',
 periods:[  
    {  
       name:'period 1',
       active:true
    },
    {  
       name:'period 2',
       active:false
    }
 ]
}
```

I want to have only one active period per unit of time, so, to activate `period 2`, I have to deactivate `period 1` and then activate `period 2`.

How can do that with only one atomic update operation?

Comment: Smells like homework

Comment: I've tried `db.mycollection.update({_id: myId }, { $set: { 'periods.active': false, 'periods.1.active': true }})`